# Command not found when trying to run a nodeschool lesson

Tags: node.js, directory

I'm not sure if this is purposeful but when running the...

```
npm install learnyounode -g
```

..command in terminal, the module is being created in my home directory. When I try to run the 'learnyounode' command from the directory that I run the npm install from I get the message 'command not found'. I've looked in the usr directory but the learnyounode directory is not in there.

After everything intalls I get the following output

```
/Users/username/npm/bin/learnyounode -> /Users/username/npm/lib/node_modules/learnyounode/learnyounode.js
learnyounode@0.4.1 /Users/username/npm/lib/node_modules/learnyounode
├── duplexer@0.1.1
├── through@2.3.4
├── boganipsum@0.1.0
├── hyperquest@0.1.8 (through@2.2.7)
├── concat-stream@1.2.1 (bops@0.0.6)
├── bl@0.6.0 (readable-stream@1.0.26)
├── through2-map@1.2.1 (through2@0.2.3, terminus@1.0.9)
└── workshopper@0.7.2 (map-async@0.1.1, tuple-stream@0.0.2, split@0.2.10, mkdirp@0.3.5,     xtend@2.1.2, colors-tmpl@0.1.0, terminal-menu@0.2.0, optimist@0.6.1, msee@0.1.1)
```

ps. I have a fresh install of node in my usr folder. I am more concerned that this problem is going to happen when I want to install other packages via NPM in the future.

Comment: I just installed another package via npm and it correctly installed it - is there something wrong with the nodeschool install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed without the -g flag and it installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install learnyounode,

This path returns:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP